# How can to use jquery regex selector?

Tags: jquery, selector

please help me.
This do not work,how correct this code??

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.0.min.js"></…; <script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js">        ; </script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $(document).on('click', 'div:regex(class,x)', function () {
                alert("sdfji");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="x">
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are selecting using class you can do it this way using regex

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("div[class^=x]").click(function () {
                    alert($(this).attr('class'));
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="x">
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LAKFv/)